# axios https lets encrypt

Tags: react-native, axios, lets-encrypt

Using `Axios` in react-native app, making a https call to the server, which `Lets Encrypt` certificate is use.

I get this error:

```
_response: 'Handshake failed',
```

What does it mean? SSL Verification fail? and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an SSL error. Something is wrong on the server letsencrypt is installed, but this really isn't enough information to tell you what it might be. Can you check / post your letsencrypt log and any additional response data?